# Memory leak when memory usage memory not big

Tags: c#, memory, memory-leaks

I had a memory leak in my app so I was started to play around with memory stuff.

My code looks roughly as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    // do some stuff
    MyObj obj = new MyObj();
    Console.WriteLine(" MEMORY: " + GC.GetTotalMemory(true));
}
```

The class `MyObj` looks as follows:

```
public class MyObj
{
    string _userName, _password, _url;

    public MyObj(string userName, string password, string url)
    {
        _userName = userName;
        _password = password;
        _url = url;

        Start(userName, password);
    }

    void Start(string userName, string password, string url)
    {
        Login(userName,password);
        Upload(filePath);

        while(FileScanNotFinished)
            Query(fileHash);

        Logout(userName,password);
    }

    void Login() { /* http request */ }

    void Upload() { /* http request */ }

    void Query() { /* http request */ }

    void Logout() { /* http request */ }
}
```

In the first iteration the memory is `807872`. After 30 iterations the memory is `819808` and then throws an `OutOfMemoryException`.

Why I get this exception where the memory is only `819808`?

Comment: What is `MyObj`? `GC.GetTotalMemory` only returns memory under the control of the .NET allocator, this is only a small part of the memory in use by a process.

Comment: `MyObj` is a class that I have `Login,Upload,Query,Logout` methods that I upload single file on each iteration to some API

Comment: You asked this exact same question the other day, please paste the constructor of your class and any other relevant construction code, otherwise noone can help you

Comment: I've run the above code snippet (added a plain MyObj class to make it into an [MCVE]) but I can't repro on .Net 4.x what you see. So either there is something relevant to your problem based on your environment or things going on in the .ctor of MyObj or in `//do some stuff`. Without seeing that code answers here can at best be a guess.

Comment: I will add full code very soon

Comment: Please don't add full code. Add code that demonstrates the exact issue.

Comment: are you doing anything with images by any chance, are you putting everything in using statments where possible or disposing them

Comment: All those HTTP requests are likely – depending on the API you use – to be allocating non-GC objects.

Comment: I found that one specific file coausing the leak